# How to sync scroll of UICollectionView's that are inside a cell?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`, that looks like Apples Calendar in Landscape mode.
Each Cell has an embedded `UICollectionView`
I need each day, to be scrollable vertically, and have the rest of the days follow the same scroll.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I tried to embed the outer collection in a scrollview, and set the scrollview content to be big enough such that it loads all the inner `UICollectionView` height, and then disable the inner scroll, so the outer scroll leads the way.

**THE PROBLEM WITH WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
this makes a big lag in the HORIZONTAL scroll of the outer `UICollectionView`, as it forces me to load many nibs outside of the screen.

Then I tried to sync the inner scrolls of the embedded `UICollectionViews` like this:

```
protocol ScrollSyncDelegate {
     func scrolledTo(offset: CGPoint)
}


extension CalendarViewController2: ScrollSyncDelegate {
    func scrolledTo(offset: CGPoint) {
        dayCollectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
            if let dayCell = cell as? DayCollectionViewCell {

                dayCell.streamableDayCollectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
                dayCell.daySideBar.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
            }

        }
        self.sideHoursCollectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)

    }
```

}

and in my inner `UICollectionView`:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self {
            scrollSyncDelegate?.scrolledTo(offset: scrollView.contentOffset)
        }
    }
```

This resulted with a very laggy scroll that doesn't decelerate at all.

How could this be achieved smoothly?

Comment: Same issue here.., Did you solve it?

Comment: I eventually implemented the whole layout in a different manner, using a page view controller using inifinite pages with a pod called Parchment